# Flipping a coin $n$ times with probability $p$, what is the associated Fisher Information?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose we have a coin with probability of being heads at $p$. Then, we flip the coin $n$ times and record the outcome. I am wondering what the Fisher information would be for this experiment. I know the formula, but would this be modeled as a Bernoulli distribution at which point the information would be $\frac{n}{p(1-p)}$? Or would it be a Binomial?

Comment: presumably here $m=n$

Comment: Apart from the order in which observations come, $n$ i.i.d. observations of a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$ and a single observation of a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$.  So both approachs lead to Fisher information of $\frac{n}{p(1-p)}$

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I fixed it. I am curious, in what case would it be a Binomial? How would the wording need to change above to be a binomial distribution? thanks!

Comment: Recording $5$ Bernoulli observations might look like `1,0,0,1,0`.  Recording one binomial observation with $n=5$ might look like `2`.  They give the same useful information